# C++ Change conditional evaluation of for loop

Tags: c++

I have a for loop where the start, stop, step are parameters that are passed in by the user:

```
for (double i(start); i <= stop; i += step)
```

This works fine if the stop > start. But I also need to support the case where the start could be larger than the stop (the step would be a negative number in this case):

```
for (double i(start); i >= stop; i += step)
```

Is there a way to support both the methods in the same for loop (by checking if start is > or < the stop). I can't figure out how to change the conditional statement of the for loop to use either >= or <= based on this condition.

There might be an obvious solution to this, but I can't think of it at the moment. Thanks in advance.

Edit: The order of the looping is important. It must iterate from start to stop.

Comment: How would you distinguish the two cases? You could then write two loops, simple as that. From that code (get it to work first), you could try to simplify it.

Comment: @cigien I have a check already that if start is > stop, the step must be negative. SO no infinite loop and the i += step will still work.

Comment: Could you add that code? I suspect you're trying to simplify a piece of code, when the simplification should maybe be done somewhere else.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yeah I can get it to work with 2 separate loops, but I'm trying to avoid that so I don't need to refactor existing code

Comment: Use std::min to initalize i and std::max to initialize loop end condition.

Comment: @doomista That might iterate in the reverse order though.

Comment: `for (double i(start); (step < 0 && i >= stop) || (step > 0 && i <= stop); i += step)` ? :)

Comment: or `sign(step) * i <= sign(step) * stop`.

Comment: @cigien Why do you think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the computation of the number of step from the actual stepping:

```
// compute how many steps
int stepCount = (stop - start) / step + 1;

// iterate over that many steps
for (int i = 0; i < stepCount; i++)
{
    double value = start + step * i;
    // use value here
}
```

To me, that's the cleanest and simplest to understand.

Comment: The calculation is not quite correct. The original loop executes once when `start <= stop < start + step`.

Comment: It doesn't seem correct either, you will have one step when stop us slightly less than start, should have 0.

Comment: Well, if you use floating point values, you relinquish the right to care about "slightly". 0.6 to 1.2 with 0.3 steps will always be "imprecise".

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
  double ss = std::copysign(1.0, step);
  for (double x = start; x*ss <= stop*ss; x += step)
  {
      //loop body
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator:

```cpp
for (double i(start); start > stop ? i >= stop : i <= stop; i += step)
```

If you want to support the case where `start > stop` but the `step` is positive, you might also use

```cpp
for (double i(start); start > stop ? i >= stop : i <= stop; start > stop ? i -= step : i += step)
```

Note however, that this use of the ternary operator is not recommended as it might confuse any reader of your code. 
It might also be more (time) efficient to just use two for loops and one if statement, since that would inflict 1 comparison before the execution of the loop, unlike this, which inflicts 1 or 2 comparisons on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate your situation because it is better to write two separate loops for both.

```
if(start < stop){
    for (double i(start); i <= stop; i += step){}
}
else{
    for (double i(start); i >= stop; i -= step){}
}
```

And please stick with integers as counters only.

Comment: This goes against the DRY principle